# Update the height for the page on toggling between two divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two divs & i am showing one div at a time. For this i am using the `toggle` method

Just refer the screen shot :

In this image when i will click `show more` the div will toggle as per the `first item` of the list. If i will click `show less` then it will collapse again.

The problem i am facing is for first & last item its fine if i will click `second or third` item then the gap is not removing. See the screenshot. I am not giving any height to any div.

The problem is coming in `mozilla` only not in any other browser...

[image]

Jquery :

```
$(".show_more_link").unbind('click').click(function(){
        var divid = $(this).attr('id');
        var show_more = "#show_more" + divid;   
        var show_less = "#show_less" + divid;
    if($(show_more).is( ':visible' )){
            $(this).text('Show more');
            $(show_more).hide();
            $(show_less).show();
          } else {
            $(this).text( 'Show less' );
             $(show_more).show();
             $(show_less).hide();
          }
    });
```

Comment: Why the mozilla creating this problem ??? Any idea guys ?

Comment: This is actually css problem. I fixed it.

Comment: post your solution here to help others with similar problem in the future

Answer (score 0):

The visibility affects just to the visibility, but not the layout. You are just making it "transparent". Use `display` instead, wich do affects the layout (display: none vs display: block)

Comment: Add html & css to the question, maybe the problem is elsewhere (perhaps wrong ids)

Comment: This problem is coming in mozilla only other browsers are working good even IE8 also

Comment: Maybe it's some kind of jquery issue with Mozilla. Id try to replace `if($(show_more).is( ':visible' )){` with something more "DOM", like `if($(show_more).css('display')!='none'){`

Comment: It's difficult without taking a look to the html. Many things are not clear for me (like using different ids for show&hide element)

Comment: Hey i solved it already....this is some css issue with mozilla ...thnx for ur time